# Best way to do a "script" for task automation in internet for raspberry pi or android

Tags: android, automation, raspberry-pi

At this moment I have a script written in AutoIt that browses some websites to check if it's online and forward some information via e-mail, but because of AutoIt only works on a "real computer", I can't put it in some "low-powered" device like a Mini Android PC or Raspberry Pi.
What I want to know is if there is some program or programming language where I can do the same thing in Android PC or Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a linux system you can use shell scripts and linux is much more powerful in automation tasks than windows. With command redirection via *pipes* you can build powerful command chains to perform most of your needed tasks. To receive a website you can use `wget`, to check for a specific line, use `grep` or `sed`. There are lots of tutorials out there. On most linux systems `mail` is built in and properly configured and normally you could even use a small `php` or `bash` script to send mails...

For Android there is a great app called `Tasker` to do automation stuff... It's really worth its costs.

Answer (score 0):

AutoIt only works on windows environments. So you could always emulate a windows environment. 
This is by far the worst idea tho.
Here's a link: http://shackspace.de/?p=3859